# Jump to Eclipse editor short key

Tags: eclipse

Currently I'm in Help view. What is short key to jump editor view? CTRL+E shows list of open files and I can select and get into it. But I would like to jum to editor that is currently visible, but not active.

Eclipse version - Mars

Comment: Could you specify the Eclipse version?

Comment: Eclipse version - Mars

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close view short key in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350160/close-view-short-key-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

There is a command `Activate Editor`, which is not bound to any key. However, you can specify a key binding to the command and use it.

Open your Preferences dialog and select `General > Keys` on the left tree, or hit `Ctrl+Shift+L` twice. Find `Activate Editor` in the right pane. You can use filter to find it fast. Then specify the key binding in the below.